# How to do multi-environment app config (config/app.php)?

Tags: config, multi-environment

I'm trying to setup different mail settings per environment. Here is my mail component that I'm defining in `config/app.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => function() {
        // Get the stored email settings
        $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getEmailSettings();

        // Override the transport adapter class
        $settings->transportType = craft\mail\transportadapters\Smtp::class;

        // Override the transport adapter settings
        $settings->transportSettings = [
            'host'              => 'localhost',
            'port'              => '1025',
            'useAuthentication' => false,
            'encryptionMethod'  => null,
            'timeout'           => '10',
        ];

        return craft\helpers\MailerHelper::createMailer($settings);
    },
],
```

How do I ensure this only applies to development environments? Multi-environment doesn't seem to work like it does for `config/general.php` and there's no multi-environment example in the [relevant documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/configuration.html#application-config). Brandon's Github comment [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1344#issuecomment-277767746) suggests that this is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work, have a look at the format of the `general.php` config file.

The key is to include the `'*'=>[]` at the start.